# Replying to a post

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically write HTML code that toggles a reply text box for the div (post) it is contained in. This is becoming a burden since I am using PHP to dynamically output each div (post) and can't uniquely link each reply button with each div.

jQuery

```
$("#reply").click(function(){
  $("#box").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Only the very first post works.

Comment: You state that `only the box is visible on the very first post`. How many boxes are supposed to be visible? You are using the `id` selector, `$("#box")`, so it should only make the 1 box with `id="box"` visible.

Comment: Well, if you use IDs, you're targeting to specific elements..Either you need classes, or you're giving same ID to different elements, which is wrong

Comment: You cant have a function that open one specific ID box and think it will append to all boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have a reply button for each `div` then you should really be using classes.

`id`'s are supposed to be unique to each page, classes on the other hand are designed to have multiple instances.

So what's happening is your jQuery selector, `$("#reply")` is finding the first `#reply` and stopping there. The same is happening with your `$("#box")` selector. Switch your `#reply`s and `#box`es to have a class, eg. `<div class="reply">`, then use the selector `$(".reply")`. You'll run into the same issue with your `#box`es too.

Without an HTML example I can't really advise you on the best thing to do here. But here is a general purpose solution:

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Nveea/

**HTML**

```
<div id="reply-1" class="reply">Reply</div>`
<div id="box-1" class="box">box 1</div>
<hr />
<div id="reply-2" class="reply">Reply</div>
<div id="box-2" class="box">box 2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box
{
    display:none;
}​​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".reply").click(function(){
    //get the associated box
    var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("reply-","");

    //toggles show and hide
    $("#box-" + index).toggle(); 
});
```

The above solution supposes you are using some kind of for-loop in PHP and can insert the iteration index into each `reply` and `box` element. If you provide some example HTML a better solution can be provided.

---

*I'll also just suggest using the jQuery function `toggle()`, which toggles an element/elements to and from display:hidden/block. This might be better than .toggleClass("hidden") in your case.*

Comment: Improved my answer a little further, it's still ultimately the same, but included the code snippets from JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

While creating button give id & a class to each button in such way that when you click you should able to get that ID. Write a function:

```
$(".class").live("click",function(){
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
   $(id).insertAfter($("#box").show()); 
});
```